# foreach mysql row from query echo out html with row values

Tags: php, mysql

So basicly what I'm trying to accomplish is that foreach row in mysql query it prints out the html with the data from that row. Here's what I have, it keeps giving me an error on my foreach.

```
<?php

$shots = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shots") or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($shots))
$data[]=$row;


foreach($shots as $data)

  if (!empty($data)){

  $id = $data["id"];
  $shotby = $data["shot"];
  $passby = $data["pass"];
  $time = $data["time"];
?>


<div class="feedbody">

    <div class="title"><?php echo $shotby; ?></div>
    <div class="feed-data">: gets a pass from <span><?php echo $passby; ?</span> and he takes a shot!</div>
    <img class="dot" src="images/dot.png" />

</div>
<?php
}

}
?>
```

Or something like that. Can anybody help point me in the right direction. I've been trying to find the answer.

**EDIT:** adding the error as requested.

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/93/7527593/html/fusionboard/includes/feed.php on line 7
```

Comment: you forgot something. The error.

Comment: Also, I know it's a coding style thing, but *please* use curly braces, even on one-line bodies like your while loop and for loop. Makes everything much more readable and one day not using them will come back to bite you with a hard to track down bug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<strike>First, if you want to access the data by name (instead of index), you need to include `MYSQL_ASSOC` as a second parameter to mysql_fetch_array, or use mysql_fetch_assoc.</strike>

Not really sure why you were copying the MySQL results to a second array just to loop through that later - you can loop through the results directly:

```
<?php
$shots = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shots") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($shots)) { ?>
<div class="feedbody">
    <div class="title"><?php echo $row["shot"]; ?></div>
    <div class="feed-data">: gets a pass from <span><?php echo $row["pass"]; ?></span> and he takes a shot!</div>
    <img class="dot" src="images/dot.png" />
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

**Update after you posted the error message:** the error from your original code was that you first went through and copied each result row into `$data`, but then in your foreach you tried to loop on `$shots` (again) and have it call each item `$data`.

What you probably wanted to do was have `foreach ($data as $item)` and then copy the properties from `$item`.

Comment: You could just make it `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($shots))` for a associative array. `:)` - upvoted though

Comment: @biotox thanks, updated answer to reflect that (been a while since I've used native PHP mysql calls, ha).

Comment: It's cause I'm not really sure what I'm doing half the time. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Agreed.  `mysql_fetch_assoc()` doesn't require anything more.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
<?php
$shots = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shots") or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($shots))
{
  $id = $row["id"];
  $shotby = $row["shot"];
  $passby = $row["pass"];
  $time = $row["time"];
?>

<div class="feedbody">

    <div class="title"><?php echo $shotby; ?></div>
    <div class="feed-data">: gets a pass from <span><?php echo $passby; ?</span> and he takes a shot!</div>
    <img class="dot" src="images/dot.png" />

</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need another closing brace? (Another "}" at the end, I mean).

Answer (score 0):

You saved your data in the $data variable, but your foreach uses the $shots variable.

Just change it to foreach($data as $something) and $something["id"] (for example) to retrieve a value

Answer (score -2):

you are using one variable instead of another.
and many useless code.

while youneed only

```
<?php foreach($data as $row) { ?> 
<div class="feedbody"> 
    <div class="title"><?php echo $row['shotby'] ?></div> 
    <div class="feed-data">: 
        gets a pass from <span><?php echo $row['passby'] ?</span> and he takes a shot!
    </div> 
    <img class="dot" src="images/dot.png" /> 
</div> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: you intend to loop through this for every column of every row?